# Are these in passives?

Tags: passive-voice

I learned English autodidactically by reading books , watching movies , video games , etc.... But, there are some things in english that confused me , such as passive forms. What's the difference between '**x cannot be stolen**' and '**x cannot be steal**'? . Are both in passive forms and have the same meaning ?

Comment: Something can be _a steal_ (meaning it’s so cheap it’s almost like you stole it rather than buying it), but _*be steal_ is not grammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first one is grammatically correct. The second one has no meaning. When something is stolen, it means that someone has stolen it. So, to answer your question, the first one is in passive form.

Comment: So you mean NO WAY the second is used to express passive ?

Comment: Yes, no way. You cannot use it.

Comment: It's a mistaken hearing. It should be  ***a steal***, with an article. But _a_ is hard to hear and often missed in speech, giving the impression it's not there. As a verb, _steal_ is present tense and infinitive, never participle or past tense. But as a noun, _a steal_, meaning a bargain, is very common as a predicate noun and therefore can follow the auxiliary _be_. Passive uses the auxiliary _be_ followed by a past participle form. _Steal_ cannot be a past participle, so this cannot be passive.

Comment: @JohnLawler If it's a mistake in *hearing* (or interpretation), it could also be *x cannot be* ***steel***, as in made of that metal.

Comment: Could be, if it makes sense in context. But that's the listener's call, not the speaker's -- and certainly not the writer's.